# Problems with fixed header and section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sticky header. I have used the bootstrap fixed-top class and it works.

The problem comes when I change the device from pc to tablet since the section stays behind the fixed header.

I have tried to put a fixed padding-top to the section but changing the size of the header when changing from PC to tablet does not work.

My header:

```
<header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="overflow: hidden">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
            <p>{{(datosEmpresaTaller | async).empresa}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
          <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
            <p>{{(datosEmpresaTaller | async).taller}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <form class="d-flex">
        <button class="btn btn-outline" type="submit" routerLink='/dashboard'> <img src="assets/icons/menu.png"
            alt="Cerrar Sesión" height="80" width="100" /></button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

My section:

```
<div>
      <section class="section" style="background-image: url('assets/img/cambiar-ruedas.png'); -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: repeat; min-height: calc(100vh);">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="left" type="button"> <img src="assets/icons/boton-actualizar.png" alt="Actualizar"
            height="50" width="70" style="margin-top: 2%;" HSPACE="10" VSPACE="10"> <img src="assets/icons/atras.png" alt="atras"
            height="50" width="70" style="margin-top: 2%;" HSPACE="10" VSPACE="10" routerLink='/picking-orders-zones'></div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-primary table-striped" id="myTable" style="margin-top: 1%;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Orden:</th>
                  <th>Zona:</th>
                  <th>Agencia:</th>
                  <th>Pendiente:</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
    
          </div>
        </div>
```

My css:

```
.section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

I need the section to stay fixed under the head regardless of the view.

[image: PC]

[image: Tablet]

Comment: Try using flex.

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap class called 'sticky-top'.

```
<div class="sticky-top">...</div>
```

Or "responsive sticky top" in bootstrap.
[bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/).
To keep the main content bumped down below the header info.